# Aplicação de Certificado Pinning em APP

Tags: java, android, ssl

Gostaria de aplicar pinning em um aplicativo, porém nunca apliquei.

Eu vi alguns artigos sobre Pinning, como o [deste link](http://blog.tempest.com.br/antonio-martins/certificate-pinning-dificultando-ataques-mitm.html), porém não explica especificamente aonde tenho que colocar, e como coloco no meu APP.

Também [achei isso](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning), porém o app é feito em java não encontrei nada relacionado.

Alguém sabe algo?

Comment: Ótima técnica, sem duvidas gostaria de ver uma resposta.